# CoreData multithread crash on iOS 8.3

Tags: multithreading, core-data

After updating device/xCode to iOS 8.3 my app starts crashing when I am doing background updating.
Here is my managedObjectContext/persistentStoreCoordinator method:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSThread *thisThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    if (thisThread == [NSThread mainThread]) {
        return self.mainContext;
    }

    NSString * threadKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", thisThread];
    NSManagedObjectContext * threadContext = nil;
    @synchronized(self.managedObjectContexts) {
        threadContext = self.managedObjectContexts[threadKey];
    }

    if (!threadContext) {
        threadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        threadContext.parentContext = self.mainContext;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:threadContext];

        @synchronized(self.managedObjectContexts) {
            [self.managedObjectContexts setObject:threadContext forKey:threadKey];
        }
    }

    return threadContext;
}

+ (NSString*)managedObjectContextKeyForThread:(NSThread*)thread {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)thread];
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
if (!persistentStoreCoordinator) {
    NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.modelURL];

    if(objectModel) {
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                                          initWithManagedObjectModel:objectModel];
        NSDictionary * options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @(YES),
                                   NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @(YES)
                                   };
        NSError* error = nil;
        if ([storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.storeURL
                                                 options:options error:&error])
        {
            persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCoordinator;
        } else {
            NSError *err = nil;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:self.storeURL error:&err];
            if ([storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.storeURL
                                                     options:options error:&error])
            {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kDatabaseRecreatedNotificationKey object:nil];
                persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCoordinator;
            }
        }
    }
}

return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

It is crashing in contextDidSave method with error message:

[image: crash]

In the first exception breakpoint in Debug Navigator it shows one more line  - "developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform"

What is wrong with my code? It worked fine prior to 8.3. Maybe, Apple has added new rules?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the reason of your problem. But you don't really need a separate managed object context for each thread, it's an outdated approach from iOS < 5. Now you can use just two contexts: one with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` to be used from the main thread and another one (the parent context) with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for background processing. Then you can just use context's  `performBlock` method to ensure that things are executing on the right thread. This article may be helpful: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well with the release of 8.3. If your case is like mine you were setting self.mainContext in viewDidLoad (You didn't show where that ivar is being set). But I can see in the debugger that fetchedResultsController is now being called before viewDidLoad. My fix was to move the setting of my equivalent of self.mainContext into the init method, in my case initWithCoder.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my case. Mine mainContext initialization is in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work and headache I have moved to [Magical Record library](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) and achieved my main goal - background data updating with Core Data.